# Task.Run( () MethodName()) and await Task.Run(async () => MethodName())

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I am trying to understand if using

```
await Task.Run(async () => MethodName())
```

in MVC 5 gives the benefits of freeing up the thread of a long running IO operation, while continuing with other code tasks in Parallel.

I know that simply using "await MethodName()" will free up the thread, but it will not move to the next line of code unit MethodName() is done executing.  (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I'd like to be able to free up the thread while the async operation is executing, as well as execute other code in parallel.  I'd like to use this in order to make multiple calls to different data sources in parallel.  Is this what "await Task.Run(async () => MethodName())" achieves?

Comment: it will still wait for the task to complete before executing next line of code.

Comment: Seems what you want to do is:  `await Task.WhenAll(...tasks...)`

Comment: Is there an alternative method that gives the benefits of both?  I'd really like to perform these calls in parallel but do not want to block multiple threads for long periods of time.

Comment: Can you post a better code example that shows the different operations you want to run asynchronously?  The async/await stuff is a feature introduced into C# 5.0 so it is available in MVC 5 projects but it is just a C# feature so you could use it in any of your C# code that will be compiled by a C# 5.0+ compliant compiler FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't do that.

Instead just don't await till you have to. So instead of doing

```
await MethodName();
DoSomeOtherWork();
```

do

```
Task yourTask = MethodName();
DoSomeOtherWork();
await yourTask;
```

This lets both the background IO work happen and your `DoSomeOtherWork()` at the same time without tying up a thread.

If you have multiple IO tasks to perform you can group them all together with a `Task.WhenAll`

```
Task<DbOneResults> dbOne= GetDbOneRecords();
Task<DbTwoResults> dbTwo = GetDbTwoRecords();
Task<DbThreeResults> dbThree = GetDbThreeRecords();

//This line is not necessary, but if you wanted all 3 done before you 
//started to process the results you would use this. 
await Task.WhenAll(dbOne, dbTwo, dbThree);

//Use the results from the 3 tasks, its ok to await a 2nd time, it does not hurt anything.
DbOneResults dbOneResults = await dbOne;
DbTwoResults dbTwoResults = await dbTwo;
DbThreeResults dbThreeResults = await dbThree;
```

This lets all 3 tasks happen at once without tying up any threads.

Comment: I probably failed to mention that they are all tasks.  Such as:

Task dbOne= GetDbOneRecords();
Task dbTwo = GetDbTwoRecords();
Task dbThree = GetDbThreeRecords();

I'd like to run all those in parallel.

Comment: So is there any reason to ever use Task.Run if this is the solution?

Comment: No, there is never a reason to use `Task.Run` when you have IO bound tasks. You are just increasing your overhead costs to start up a extra thread and causing your program to run slower. `Task.Run` is only to offload CPU bound tasks while you do other CPU bound tasks. If you (or your framework) are not doing anything else while you are waiting for `Task.Run` to finish you should not be using it for CPU bound tasks either.

Comment: @blgrnboy I updated the answer again showing how you could use the results from the 3 methods if the methods did return results.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the resulting task in some variable and await it later. Ie:

```
var task = LongRunningMethodAsync();

SomeOtherWork();
SomeWorkOtherThanBefore();

awai task;
```

You can also store resulting tasks of many methods and wait for all of them:

```
var tasks = new Task[] {
   FirstMethodAsync(),
   SecondMethodAsync(),
   ThirdMethodAsync()
};

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```